# Accessing an array of vectors trouble

Tags: ruby, vector

My code looks like this:

```
a = IO.readlines("input.txt").map { |line| Vector.[](line.split) }
```

Now I want to access a single component of the first vector within my **a** array. I'm writing the following to address a vector:

```
puts a[0]
```

The behavior is pretty much expected - I receive the following:

```
Vector[1.2357, 2.1742, -5.4834, -2.0735]
```

Now let's try to address a single component this way:

```
puts a[0][0]
```

and voila, I receive a list of all the vector components,like:

```
1.2357
2.1742
-5.4834
-2.0735
```

How come? Maybe the last attempt was wrong? How do I correctly address a scalar inside a vector within an array?

Comment: Notice that the variable a is an array that contains a vector, is that ok? try puts a.inspect

Comment: You pushed me to notice, that in Vector constructor I'm putting not required link to array (with an * sign), but the actual array. That was a mistake. Post a simple answer here, so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to your code I think the array construction should be:

```
a = IO.readlines("input.txt").map { |line| Vector[*line.split] }
```